# How do I obtain the derivative of $\frac{x^2}{x-y}$?

Tags: derivatives

$ d=\frac{x^2}{x-y}$ and im trying to find d'.

do i take it as $x^2(x-y)^{-1}$ ? That seems to give me the wrong answer.

If i take it like that, i get $ 2x(x-y)^{-1}  +  x^2(-1)(x-y)^{-2}$.

is this correct?

with respect to $x$

Comment: Derivative with respect to what?

Comment: You want to find the derivative of $$\frac{x^2}{x-y}$$ with respect to $x$?

Comment: yes sorry with respect to x

Comment: Is $y$ a different variable? A function of $x$?

Comment: y is a different variable

Comment: You should set $f(x,y)$ equal to your expression and ask for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.

Comment: Yes, what you got is correct.

Comment: @user65678 Is this problem from multivariable calculus, or from calculus one?  (just making sure)

Answer (score 3):

If we have $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{x-y}$ and we are only differentiating with respect to $x$ we can use either the product rule, or the quotient rule. I prefer the product rule though. So here's what we do :

$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial (x^2(x-y)^{-1})}{\partial x}= 2x(x-y)^{-1}+x^2(-1)(x-y)^{-2}$$

Comment: thank you. im on the right track it seems. guess i just messed up somewhere on my way to the final answer in my problem.

Comment: @Calc1DropOut what prime means for the function of two variables?

Comment: @Kaster I edited to make it more clear.

Comment: @Calc1DropOut I bet you meant $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}$ :)

Comment: Yeah ;) thanks!